# composing a list of list

Tags: prolog

Instead of pressing 'a' to see all results on terminal, I want store them in list of list 
([ [] ] ). How can I do that over using newly created function namely bar ?

I have a function;

```
foo(X, Y).
    ^  ^
    ^  returns a list ex [1,2,3,4]
    ^
    input
```

What I have done :

```
 bar(A,B) :- foo(X,Y), B is [Y|B], bar(A,B) .
```

But above code is not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bar(A,B) :- foo(X,Y), B is [Y|B], bar(A,B) .
                        ^     ^   ^
```

There are 3 problems:

1. **is** evaluates arithmetic, **=** must be used
2. but then `B = [Y|B]` would create a cyclic structure, SWI-Prolog can
   handle it, but I dubt it's your intent
3. `bar(A,B)` it's *exactly* equal to rule' head. This is not necessarily an error, because instantiated variables actually can change the execution flow, but I can't see why you use here.

findall/3 should solve your problem:

```
bar(A,B) :- findall(Y, (X=A, foo(X,Y)), B).
```

I've set `X=A`, otherwise `A` is useless. A cleaner way to express this is

```
bar(A,B) :- findall(Y, foo(A,Y), B).
```